# Transform number to xy coordinates

Tags: algorithm, math

I need to generate belwo sequence based on order number.

```
1-(0,0)
2-(1,0)
3-(0,1)
4-(1,1)
5-(0,2)
6-(1,2)
7-(0,3)
8-(1,3)
9-(0,4)
10-(1,4)
11-(0,5)
12-(1,5)
```

When I input number I need the xy coordinates.

Any pointer on the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sample data, you see, that the first number of the result is 1 if the input number (x) is even. And 0 if the input number is odd. The second term is `div (x-1) 2` in case of `odd x` and `div (x-2) 2` in case of `even x`.

In Haskell, btw., it looks exactly like the text above:

```
f :: Int -> (Int,Int)
f x
  | odd x = (0, div (x-1) 2)
  | even x = (1, div (x-2) 2)
```

Applying f to each number in 1..12

```
fmap f [1..12]
```

yields:

> [(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(0,3),(1,3),(0,4),(1,4),(0,5),(1,5)]

Which is exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It is the following formula for the input `i`:

```
(1 - (i % 2) ,(i // 2) - (1 - (i % 2)))
```

The first element of the pair is `0` if `i` is odd and is `1`, if `i` is even. Hence, it is `1 - (i % 2)`. The second element is integer division of the input over `2` minus the first element. Therefore it is `(i // 2) - (1 - (i % 2))`

Comment: What programming language uses // for integer division ?

Comment: For the second element, I would consider `(i-1)//2` as a simpler expression.

Comment: @chmike `//` for python 3.

Comment: @chmike thanks. You're right. I just desired to explain the relation of the first and the scond element.

Answer (score 0):

The first number is `!(n & 1)`, the second number is `floor((n - 1) / 2)`. As a C program it becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calc1(int n)
  {
  return !(n & 1);
  }

int calc2(int n)
  {
  return (int)((n - 1) / 2);
  }

int main()
  {
  for(int n = 1 ; n <= 12 ; ++n)
    printf("n=%d -> (%d, %d)\n", n, calc1(n), calc2(n));

  return 0;
  }
```

the output of which is

```
n=1 -> (0, 0)                                                                                                                                                                      
n=2 -> (1, 0)                                                                                                                                                                      
n=3 -> (0, 1)                                                                                                                                                                      
n=4 -> (1, 1)                                                                                                                                                                      
n=5 -> (0, 2)                                                                                                                                                                      
n=6 -> (1, 2)                                                                                                                                                                      
n=7 -> (0, 3)                                                                                                                                                                      
n=8 -> (1, 3)                                                                                                                                                                      
n=9 -> (0, 4)                                                                                                                                                                      
n=10 -> (1, 4)                                                                                                                                                                     
n=11 -> (0, 5)                                                                                                                                                                     
n=12 -> (1, 5)
```